# Custom event when PrintQueue becomes 0

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this:

```
 foreach (PrintQueue pq in myPrintQueues)
            {
                printcargas++;
            }
            if (printcargas > 0)
            {
                this.Close();
                Imprimiendo imprimiendo = new Imprimiendo();
                imprimiendo.Show();
            }
```

but I want to make a custom event in "Imprimiendo" form, that listens for PrintQueues, and once PrintQueues become 0, close the form. How is this possible?

I thought of making several timers checking for PrintQueues, but I think there might be a better option.

Comment: It is not a sensible question.  A PrintQueue is a system object, they very, *very* rarely get added or removed.  So this is a feature that just never ever gets used.  Maybe you are actually talking about print *jobs*.  Otherwise rather awful classes, you never want to use them unless you got your back to the wall.  The only reason they got added to .NET is because WPF required them.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

[PrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is derived from object and doesn't have an event model to it:

> ```
> System.Object
>  System.Printing.PrintSystemObject
>   System.Printing.PrintQueue
> ```

So, yes, I guess you will need a `Timer` to watch the queue or queues you have.

You could question one or more of its properties, like [`IsWaiting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.iswaiting(v=vs.110).aspx) or  its [`QueueStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.queuestatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

**If** you have control over all [`PrintDocuments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you may watch those for the [`EndPrint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.endprint(v=vs.110).aspx) event.